# How to $graphLookup with dynamic parent references in Mongoose

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongoose, nosql, graphlookup

Let's assume I'm making a react app to manage what's in my restaurant's fridge. I have three collections:

- Refrigerators (contains jars or food items)
- Jars (contains jars or food items; exists in refrigerators or other jars)
- Food Items (exists in jars or fridge)

Refrigerators:

```
[{
   "name": "abc",
   "temp": 23,
}, ...]
```

Jars:

```
[{
   "name": "jar1",
   "parent": 
   {
      "type": "jar",
      "id": "id_of_parent_jar"
   }
}, {
   "name": "jar2",
   "parent": 
   {
      "type": "refrigerator",
      "id": "id_of_parent_refrigerator"
   }
},
 ...]
```

Food Items:

```
[{
   "name": "jar1",
   "parent": 
   {
      "type": "jar",
      "id": "id_of_parent_jar"
   }
},
 ...]
```

A problem arises in any situation where we are using all three collections:

`food -> jar -> fridge`

There is no way to tell graphLookup to change the `from` field when the jar parent is a fridge. To further complicate things:

`food -> jar -> jar -> fridge`

introduces another problem; you cannot assume that depth `1` will be a jar, and depth `2` will be a fridge. Depth `1+n` could be any number theoretically until we hit a `refrigerator` reference.

How would you get `graphLookup` to dynamically change the `from` collection based on the `parent.type` field of either the `jar` or `food_item`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no great way to do this in Mongo. Instead, I opted to implement an "array of ancestors" model that would not have to regressively query.

https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/tutorial/model-tree-structures-with-ancestors-array/

Instead, each time a new object is made, the object will simply append itself to a copy of it's parent's ancestor array, expanding it's ancestor array by `n + 1`. Each time a further child is created, this process repeats; no need for regressive querying as the previous tree position is stored.

**Note that this makes moving tree items around very hard**

*If* you need to move things around, you'd have to either:

1. Implement an algorithm to update a parent's position and all of it's children's array of ancestors (costly)
2. Make a separate collection where each document references either a `food`, `jar`, or `fridge`, and use `graphLookup` there, as everything is in the same collection.